# FOSElasticaBundle and Gedmo translatable

Tags: symfony, multilingual, foselasticabundle

I want to use FOSElasticaBundle on my symfony2 project.

Both bundles are correctly configured and functionals.

I already use Gedmo Translatable to handle multilingual but I cannot find how to implement gedmo translations in my elastic mapping or to build an elastic query which get results with a chosen locale.

Anyone already experienced this problem ?

Comment: Hello @GregOs. Did you find any solution so far ? I have the same situation right now. Thx.

Comment: hello @pauletienney, I finally decided to create my own translation system and not to use Gedmo anymore.